# how can run java program with Jenkins if the program takes user input

Tags: jenkins

I know how to run  a simple hello file . I've put javac and java command as part of the job, but don't know how to run a file which takes input from the user.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Show what have you tried so far.

Answer (score 0):

Create a [jenkins job](https://support.cloudbees.com/hc/en-us/articles/218864657-How-do-I-create-a-parameterized-project-?) which can accept [parameters](https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Parameterized+Build) and pass those parameters to your java program

Comment: Thats my question. how to pass the parameter to the java program

Comment: How did you create job?Did you use parameterized job plugin?